# How to return error code when using tee in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, pipe, tee

I want to use `tee` to write the output of `any command (first command)` to a file, but I want to get the return code from the `first command` instead of the `tee` command.

**Example 1: The following code will return 1 and it is expected:**

```
cp -unknown-args "hello"
echo "return code is $?"

---output---
cp: invalid option -- 'k'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
return code is 1
```

**Example 2: The following code will return 0 and it is unexpected:**

```
cp -unknown-args "hello" | tee test.txt
echo "return code is $?"

---output---
cp: invalid option -- 'k'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
return code is 0
```

I want to make "`Example 2`" to `return 1` if the `first command` has any error.
Is it possible and how to do if yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `set -o pipefail`, this will propagate nonzero exits to later pipe members